# White branches on citrus tree, is this normal?

Tags: diagnosis, fungus, citrus, branches

I'm seeing the branches to my citrus tree turn white.  When I cut them, it's all dead.  Is that normal or is it a fungus or something ?  Please refer to the attached photo.  It's happening to several of the citrus in my yard.

[image]